# malfunction if in bashscript

Tags: bash, if-statement, cmp

I have a code:

```
flag=true

if cmp -s item1 item2 ; then
   if test flag = true; then
      echo 'a'
   else 
      echo 'b'
   fi
fi
```

and for somereason only the else is triggered and I get 'b', why is that?

Comment: because "flag" is not equal to "true"

Comment: You want $flag = true

Comment: ...or, rather, `test "$flag" = true`, with the quotes; otherwise you get a syntax error from `test` if `flag` is empty.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have told you that your `flag` variable was unused if you submitted it this code.